# laravel middleware array_key_exists() error

Tags: php, laravel

My middleware code
php version 5.6.32-1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Session, Closure;

class AuthLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Session::has('account')) {
          return redirect('/admin/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And I get this error

> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

what's happend with it?

There is not any error on my mac, but it's happen on my linode server

Comment: clear cache this is a trial

Comment: What version of Laravel? 5.5 requires `7.0`+

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error due to the following reason :

```
$arr = [[0] => 10,[1] => 20,[2] => 30,[3] => 40,[4] => 50];
```

let's say you search for values 10 or 30

$k = array_search('10', $arr);

now $k will hold [0]

and if do this

array_key_exists($k, $arr);

you will get array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer because $k i,e 0 is treated as boolean not string or int but if we have searched 30 then this issue will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who facing this problem, I solved this by clearing config cache using:

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

or also you can using command (this will clear all cache in your application, including route, config, view and app cache):

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

And this is how I check if session exist:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->session()->exists('session_name')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```